How do I get the tool options menu for inset faces back at the bottom of the screen?
The Inset Faces tool (shortcut i) used to show an options menu at the bottom of the editor window. It has disappeared—I have no idea how; maybe I mis-clicked or accidentally hit the wrong menu—but I can't find how to get it back. The options are now in white text at the top of the screen. Is there a way to restore it?
[EDIT / SOLUTION:]
The menu will only appear after confirm by LMB or Enter.
The other tools still do show their options, e.g. insert mesh allows me to tweak things like I was used to.
Using Blender 4.1.0 on Linux Mint, 21.1 Vera, Xfce
How it looks now:

How it used to look:
Screenshot from the tutorial I'm folowing. It is in 3.2.0 Alpha


Don't know about Linux, but on my Windows PC the tool options only appear after I have used the tool. While I'm using the tool the values are shown at the top left. But this is normal behaviour also for moving, rotating, scaling, extruding, beveling etc. So I have to press I, do some insetting (does not really matter since I want to adjust it with the options), left-click to confirm the inset and then the options appear at the bottom left and I can change them.

Hi Gordon, You are right. It does only appear after LMB to confirm and then you can change the parameters. I was confused how to get the "Individual" option and got stuck assuming I needed to do that before confirming.

Well, that's what the info at the top left is good for, it shows you the shortcuts for options...

Hello Smitje. Please don't add "Solved" to your question or title. Instead we encourage you to post an answer below with a short description of the solution and what steps you took to reach it. Perhaps add a few images illustrating the workflow and final results. See How do I write a good answer?

Hi Harry, thanks for the improvement. I now added and answer. There appears to be a different behavior in object mode and in edit mode and I wonder if this is a design choice or has some other reason. What would be the proper way to ask that followup question? Should I put that with the original question, with the answer or start a new question altogether?

Apparently in edit mode the menu only appears after confirming an action with Enter or LMB. This is the case for other tools besides inset as well. I tested with loop-cut ctrl-r and rip v. While in object mode e.g. after adding a cube, the menu appears immediately after selecting the object from the menu.
Select the face and hit i, the options are in white at the top:

After confirming with by LMB or Enter, the menu appears:

